# Java - Regex backreferences in array

Tags: java, regex, backreference

Is there any way to split a Java String using a regular expression and return an array of backreferences?

As a simple example, say I wanted to pull the username & provider from a simple email address (letters only).

```
String pattern = "([a-z]+)@([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]{3})";
String email = "user@email.com";

String[] backrefs = backrefs(email,pattern);

System.out.println(backrefs[0]);
System.out.println(backrefs[1]);
System.out.println(backrefs[2]);
```

This should output

```
user
email
com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes from `java.util.regex` pacakge.

```
String pattern = "([a-z]+)@([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]{3})";
String email = "user@email.com";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(email);
// Check if there is a match, and then print the groups.
if (matcher.matches())
{
    // group(0) contains the entire string that matched the pattern.
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```